# How to convert values in a matrix based on a list of rules without using for-loop in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace, rule

I have a matrix with either 1s or 0s.

```
xmat = matrix(round(runif(12),0), ncol=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    1
```

I also have a rule table, which is a list.

```
a = c(0.2, 0.5)
b = c(0.5, 0.6)
c = c(0.8, 0.1)
names(a) = c("0", "1")
names(b) = c("0", "1")
names(c) = c("0", "1")

ruletable = list(a, b, c)

[[1]]
  0   1 
0.2 0.5 

[[2]]
  0   1 
 0.5 0.6 

[[3]]
  0   1 
 0.8 0.1
```

I need to replace the 1s and 0s in each column of xmat with the corresponding values specified by the rule table. For example, the first column of xmat is (0, 1, 1, 1), which needs to be converted into (0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) using ruletable[[1]]. Similarly, the second column of xmat (1, 0, 0, 0) needs to be converted into (0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) using ruletable[[2]]. Since this is potentially a huge matrix, I am looking for a solution without using for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: time complexity is still m*n, why not using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be reasonably efficient:

```
vapply(
  1:length(ruletable), 
  function(x) ruletable[[x]][xmat[, x] + 1L],
  numeric(nrow(xmat))
)
```

original matrix (`set.seed(1)`):

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    1    1    1
```

and result:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.2  0.5  0.8
# [2,]  0.2  0.6  0.8
# [3,]  0.2  0.6  0.8
# [4,]  0.5  0.6  0.1
```

Comment: That 1:length(ruletable) thing does not count as a for-loop, right?

Comment: @user3193265, why don't you try this and see how it goes?  No matter what, at the lowest level (i.e. FORTRAN, machine code, whatever) there will be a loop to do this.  `vapply` is pretty efficient.

Comment: @user3193265, not technically, it's not a `for` loop.  But ultimately this will get implemented as loop in either C or FORTRAN.  `for` loops are not inherently slow.  They get a bad rap because they are often associated with growing vectors, which is bad news.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask what does that +1L do?

Comment: @user3193265 - the values in `xmat` are 0 and 1, adding +1 (or +1L) makes these become 1 and 2, selecting the appropriate value from each vector in the `ruletable` list. I'll plug my own answer by pointing out it relies on the names of the list, and not a positional lookup.

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` answer:

```
xmat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1),nrow=4)
mapply(function(x,y) y[as.character(x)], data.frame(xmat),ruletable)

   X1  X2  X3
0 0.2 0.6 0.1
1 0.5 0.5 0.1
1 0.5 0.5 0.8
1 0.5 0.5 0.1
```

If you don't want the names, they are easy to remove:

```
unname(mapply(function(x,y) y[as.character(x)], data.frame(xmat),ruletable))
```

Comment: This also works. They should allow people to mark multiple answers! Thanks!